# whcih version of google_ml_kit and google_mlkit_face_detection should be used to execute processimage method

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, face-detection

```
final List<Face> faces = await GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector().processImage(inputImage);
or
final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);

I am using this way to detect faces that are already registered. Input Image is not null. It shows an instance of an input image when I print its value.
```

I have written a function to draw a bounding box once the face appears and hit the API. But the bounding box is not coming up.

tried updating versions of Google ml kit, google ml kit face detection to the latest